# Multi-value field to create multiple records?

Tags: ms-access

I have a table connecting three tables, one each for staff, items and programmes:

> Staff 1-1 Programme (Each staff member can only be assigned to one programme at any given time)
>   Staff 1-many Items (Each staff member may request for more than one inventory item)

I create a form for this table, on which I create a combo box to allow the user to select multiple items.

How can I make it such that if for instance the user enters his/her staff ID and his/her programme code and checks off three items, then three records are saved in the table (instead of one record but with multiple values for that field)?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you cannot use a multivalue field to created a new record for each checked combo box item unless you want to get into really complex VB Scripting.  **However, you can do a printout of multivalue fields by creating and running a SQL statement, which does actually present the information exactly how your describing/requesting.**

You can set the **`Row Source`** for a textbox or combobox on a form by going into the forms **`Design View`** and then click on the field text entry area then under **`Property Sheet > Data >`**  set a SQL Statement to equal different tables to acquire the values you are referencing and then set the **`Control Source`** (above Row Source) to the output fieldname/table where you want to store that information.

```
SELECT tblName.FieldName1.Value AS FieldName, tblName.FieldName2, tblName.FieldName3 FROM tblName;
```

**`tblName.FieldName.Value AS`** something that's not **`x.Value`** because **`x.Value`** is the individual entries for each multivalued combo box entry for the entire table where this information is "~stored".

If you run the SQL Query above (obviously change to what your actual tables and fieldnames are) then you will see a temporary table (a view) with all the individual values of the multivalues like a printout.

### OR

CREATE TABLES: Where I mention references do the steps above but remember you may need to set a condition using **`WHERE`** something **`=`** something **`AND OR`** something.

> Staff Programme Table: [UniqueRowID], [StaffNum], [Name], [ProgrammeName], etcetera

The ProgrammeName column references the ProgrammeName in Programme Lookup table.  You need to set the fieldname "Display Control" under "Lookup" to combobox then set Row Source to SQL statement like previous mentioned so it knows where to get the values for the programme name.

> Programme Lookup Table: [UniqueRowID], [ProgrammeName], etcetera

This contains all values that exist. Easy to update and maintain.

> Staff Items Table: [UniqueRowID], [ItemName], etcetera

The ItemName column references the ItemName in Inventory Lookup table.  You need to set the fieldname "Display Control" under "Lookup" to combobox then set Row Source to SQL statement like previous mentioned so it knows where to get the values for the inventory item.

> Inventory Lookup Table: [UniqueRowID], [ItemName], etcetera

This contains all values that exist. Easy to update and maintain

### OR

Alternatively, create another table that contains the values you want.  Then create a SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO newTableName(newfield1, newfield2, newfield3, etc)
SELECT sourcetblName.sourceFieldName1.Value AS FieldName, sourcetblName.sourceFieldName2, sourcetblName.sourceFieldName3 FROM SourcetblName;
```